# is it possible to call a device function inside a Thrust functor?

Tags: cuda, gpu, thrust

I would like to call a device function inside a thrust functor but would not even know how to start. This is an obvious need, since there are cases that functor size is big and therefore, needs to be split to functions.

A minimum example is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: What device function? Something from the CUDA math library, or something you wrote yourself?

Comment: it's the function I write to run on device. It is designated with __device__

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do this in a fashion very similar to how it would be done in ordinary CUDA C++ code.  Define your `__device__` function (perhaps mark it `__host__` `__device__`) exactly as you would in ordinary CUDA device code, and use that in a thrust functor operator, just as you would use it anywhere else in CUDA device code.

Here is a trivial example that demonstrates calling a `__host__ __device__` function from a functor operator, as well as calling a CUDA built-in math library function from the functor operator:

```
$ cat t9.cu
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/transform.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>

template <typename T>
__host__ __device__ T square(T &s){
  return s*s;
}

struct my_math
{
  __host__ __device__
  float operator()(float &r){
   return log2f(square(r));
  }
};

int main(){

  std::vector<float> h_data = {1,2,4,8,16};
  thrust::device_vector<float> d_data = h_data;
  thrust::transform(d_data.begin(), d_data.end(), d_data.begin(), my_math());
  thrust::copy(d_data.begin(), d_data.end(), std::ostream_iterator<float>(std::cout, ","));
  std::cout << std::endl;
}


$ nvcc -arch=sm_35 -std=c++11 -o t9 t9.cu
$ ./t9
0,2,4,6,8,
$
```

Comment: Thank you, Mr. Crovella. I tried your code and it worked nicely. It meant I have a bug somewhere in my code. I could not find any sample in thrust github before this post